# Smarty Template date_format gives unpredictable results

Tags: php, smarty

I am passing a timestamp into a Smarty Template, and using `date_format` gives unpredictable results. Here's an example template that demonstrates the problem most elegantly:

```
{"1456602208"}
{"1456602208"|date_format}
{"1432808316"}
{"1432808316"|date_format}
```

The output of this template:

```
1456602208
Oct 19, 2208
1432808316
May 28, 2015
```

The second date is correctly formatted. The first one, however, should be

```
Feb 27, 2016
```

Why is this?

Comment: If you try from int is it working ok? To have like this: `{1456602208|date_format}` And what version of smarty you have? I see that there are some changes to numeric input from version Smarty-2.6.10. So if you have a older version maybe here is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid this is to cast to `int` the timestamp. Now it's a numeric `string`.

Smarty did some changes in 2.6.10 to use all numeric input values as timestamp, but before was not always the case.

As I can see the first timestamp ends in `2208` and also the year returned for that timestamp is `2208`, so I think smarty think it's not a timestamp, but a date formatted somehow.

See more [here (smarty doc)](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl)

Comment: Yep looks like you're right on all accounts. It's an older Smarty version and not guessing the format correctly. So we'll upgrade Smarty, plus switch to ISO8601 datestamps instead of unix timestamps. Cheers.